# R igraph edge colors

Tags: r, networking, igraph

I am creating a graph from an adjacency matrix, and would like to color the edges by the color of the nodes.
Do you know how I can do this?

Here is my code, in case it helps:

```
g1<-graph.adjacency(common 
                    ,mod=c('directed') 
                    ,weighted=TRUE
                    ,diag=FALSE 
                    ,add.colnames=NULL 
                    ,add.rownames=NA)
plot(g1
 , layout=layout.lgl
 , vertex.color=palette(rainbow(26))
 , vertex.size=degree(g1)*0.1
 , edge.curved=T
 , edge.width=edge.betweenness(g1)*0.1
 , edge.arrow.size=0.07)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is what you are looking for, but all the colors are blue with the code below.

```
plot(g1
 , layout=layout.lgl
 , vertex.color="blue"
 , vertex.size=degree(g1)*0.1
 , edge.color="blue"
 , edge.curved=T
 , edge.width=edge.betweenness(g1)*0.1
 , edge.arrow.size=0.07)
```

Also, check out help for `plot.igraph` which is used when you use `plot`